# How can I add Autofill in my geo location HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I want to add autofill in my button so as soon as the user starts
writing the name of the location, it should suggest the name using google library.
Currently I am taking the full input from user and hitting a button to show the longitude and latitude which is not accurate if the name of location is long.

```
</head>
<!-- To use Geocoding from Google Maps V3 you need to link https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false -->
<body>
<div>
     <h3> Enter an adress and press the button</h3>

    <input id="address"  type="text" placeholder="Enter address here" />
    <button id="btn">Get LatLong</button>
    <div>
        <p>Latitude:
            <input type="text" id="latitude" readonly />
        </p>
        <p>Longitude:
            <input type="text" id="longitude" readonly />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    /* This showResult function is used as the callback function*/

function showResult(result) {
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = result.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = result.geometry.location.lng();
}

function getLatitudeLongitude(callback, address) {
    // If adress is not supplied, use default value 'Ferrol, Galicia, Spain'
    address = address || 'Ferrol, Galicia, Spain';
    // Initialize the Geocoder
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                callback(results[0]);
            }
        });
    }
}

var button = document.getElementById('btn');

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    getLatitudeLongitude(showResult, address)
});
var addressbutton = document.getElementById('address');

addressbutton.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { 
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    getLatitudeLongitude(showResult, address)
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is like working on the whole application and not on a specific problem you are facing. **You are not calling the Google Maps API** in your code at all so you cannot use the Place Autocomplete API if you do not implement the API code correctly. [Do your search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) before dumping your code randomly in here

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API has an autocomplete method `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);`. The method will do all the hard work for you, it will display results depending on the location entered.

You should get the input by using  `document.getElementById('latitude')`.

In your situation it should look like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('latitude')
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

Google provide some [example code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

The documentation for the [autocomplete class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Autocomplete)